I am trying to populate from email dynamically using codesnipet in marketing cloud in marketing cloud i am getting the below error what is issue
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
belowis my codesnip below are the snips



Can you tried wrapping your ContentBlockByID('ContentID') call within a TreatAsContent()
%%=TreatAsContent(ContentBlockByID('ContentID'))=%%

